# SSAS Dynamical Partitioning Sync

Tags: synchronization, ssas, partitioning

I have SSAS model (Tabular) on File System. I work with this model in BIDS, developing new features and then deploy it to the server. After that I have SSIS package which dynamically creates partitions for this model on the server. Once the partitions were created, the model is `"ahead"` compared to the model on the file system.

Is there any elegant way how to sync these two models? Or I have to always import the model (project) from the server when I want to work with it and develop additional features?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any source control software like Team Foundation Server or Git.

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a bit on this? I am using Git but cant imagine what exactly you thinking about how this should work.